# What are the best practices for accessing android resources from ViewModel?

Tags: android, solid-principles

I am working my way into the clean-code-pattern and came across the following question to which I unfortunately did not find an answer:

What is the best solution to access android resources from the ViewModel, like strings, colors, etc.

Maybe I just missed something.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best solution to access android resources from the
> ViewModel, like strings, colors

I would not do it. I would `emit` the `int` representation of the resource to the view (activity/fragment/dialog). There I have access to the `Resources` object use it to get the real resource

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the application context in your ViewModel, works well for strings and dimensions afaik.

A little **warning** for colors and drawables with this approach, if the Activity/Fragment use a custom theme (not the main app theme), getColor() from the Activity/Fragment or from the application context could be different (maybe it can also be a problem if you use dimensions indirections, not tested).

The [Blackbelt approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63780176/1898596) is good but can be limiting if you've to make some work on the resources, like adding Spans to a String, and you want to unit-test the resulting Spannable from the VM in isolation.